# How do check the mountpoint in Linux with for loop

Tags: linux, bash

I want to write a Bash script, to check if a mountpoint exist. If it does then do 'something' if not 'sleep for 5 sec'.

I want to write a for loop, so that if it is mounted initially, I can check the same condition until its true

```
if mountpoint -q /foo/bar; then
   /etc/init.d/iptables
else 
   sleep 5
fi
```

How can I write the for loop to check the mountpoint until its exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
mnt_path=/mnt/
while ! mountpoint -q "$mnt_path"; do
    # mountpoint does not exist
    sleep 5
done
# while loop exited, meaning mount point now exists
cat /etc/init.d/iptables
```

I would recommend introducing a time-out.

Answer (score 0):

If your objective is to hold off on starting iptables until the mountpoint exists, you could do the following:

```sh
while ! mountpoint -q /foo/bar; do
    sleep 5
done

/etc/init.d/iptables
```

The loop condition is the return code of `mountpoint -q /foo/bar`, which will be `1` for a nonexistent mount and `0` for an existing mount. The loop will continue until `mountpoint` returns `0` (meaning the mountpoint now exists), then the next command starting iptables will run.